# Making parts of spreadsheet range absolute using vba

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for being an awesome community, I've learned a ton from this great forum.

I have worksheet with a column of customer names, the column next to that has customer ID numbers and the column next to that one should have year to date sales, which is what I'm working on.

Here's my code in vba:

```
Range("C2:C134").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(SUMIFS(VA05NDump!RC14:R" & CN & "C14, VA05NDump!RC5:R"    & CN & "C5,Customers!RC[-1],VA05NDump!RC3:R" & CN & "C3,""YOR""))"
```

C2:C134 is not changing. CN is the name of my variable that stores how many sales orders are entered. So basically I want it to insert an equation in the range C2:C134, the summing range is the first range, the criteria is the cell to the immediate left (customer ID number), then the last criteria is that it has to be a "YOR" in order to be summed.

The equation that results in C2 is:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(VA05NDump!$N2:$N$1056,VA05NDump!$E2:$E$1056,Customers!B2,VA05NDump!$C2:$C$1056,"YOR"))
```

And then the cells below that are similar except the 2s have increased to 3s and below that to 4s etc etc.

So my question is: why are the three 2s not absolute? i.e. $N$2, $E$2, and $C$2? They don't have brackets around them?

Help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seconds after I typed this up I noticed my mistake....

I was not adding "1" after the R in my equations:

i.e.
VA05NDump!RC5:" & CN & "C5 needs to be VA05NDump!R1C5:" & CN & "C5

Comment: 23 more hours before I can green tick my own answer :)

Comment: Ah, I can see how that could be confusing!